# Angular guards for navigating to a parent route

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I've got an application with the following routes:

- /root/foo
- /root/bar
- /root/foo/(outlet:X)
- /root/bar/(outlet:X)

Navigating to `/root/foo` or `/root/bar` will compute a value X and redirect to `/root/foo/(outlet:X)` or `/root/bar/(outlet:X)` respectively.

Is there a way to implement a Guard such that clicking a router link to `/root/foo` from `/root/foo/(outlet:X)` will be prevented?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a [canDeactivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate) guard, checking the current and destination urls and preventing the navigation in that specific cases.

Comment: That was my first attempt. I tried adding a canActivate guard to the parent routes (/root/foo and /root/bar) as well as the child routes for the outlet, and none of them trigger when navigating from /root/foo/(outlet:X) to /root/foo.

Comment: Are `/root/foo/(outlet:X)` and `/root/bar/(outlet:X)` children of the corresponding routes? If so you might need to wait for `canDeactivateChild` https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11836 to be in master

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by using a CanDeactivate guard, but on the child components.

Route example:

`{
    path: 'root/foo',
    component: ListComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        canDeactivate: [CanNavigateToParentRouteGuard],
        component: ChildComponent,
        outlet: 'outlet'
      }
    ]
  },`

Guard:

  `canDeactivate(component: ChildComponent, currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    currentState: RouterStateSnapshot, nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    return !currentState.url.startsWith(nextState.url);
  }`